# Nginx performance issue

Tags: node.js, performance, nginx, apachebench

I am having some performance issues with Nginx.

I've got a single Nginx server sitting in front of 4 node.js applications. The node application doesn't do anything fancy, it just loops through the expressJS stack and doesn't access any external DB sources, etc.

I'm using ApacheBench to get a benchmark of how my application performs.  When I use a single server in my `upstream` rule, I get a constant `1000 req/s` throughput.  For example:

```
upstream cp_backend {
    server 10.134.14.128:5000;
    keepalive 32;
}
```

Returns `1000 req/s`.  When I add a second node application (running on a second server), for example:

```
upstream cp_backend {
    server 10.134.14.128:5000;
    server 10.134.34.226:5000;
    keepalive 32;
}
```

I see around `2000 req/s` throughput (as expected).

However, as soon as I add more than 2 backend servers, the app no longer scales linearly.  For example:

```
upstream cp_backend {
    server 10.134.14.128:5000;
    server 10.134.34.226:5000;
    server 10.134.26.172:5000;
    keepalive 32;
}
```

Only returns about `2500 req/s`, instead of `3000` as expected.  Similarly:

```
upstream cp_backend {
    server 10.134.14.128:5000;
    server 10.134.34.226:5000;
    server 10.134.26.172:5000;
    server 10.134.26.178:5000;
    keepalive 32;
}
```

Only return about `3000 req/s`, instead of `4000` as expected.

To give some more background.  I have tested another (non nodeJS) application running on these same sets of servers and I'm able to get upwards of `17k req/s`, so I know Nginx and my testing machine is capable of reaching those numbers.  It's also worth mentioning that the `content-length` was actually bigger on the 17k test than the node app.

Each node app is running on a separate VM with its own resources. When using simple tools like `top`, I don't see any major bottlenecks. Plus, I know when using a single upstream server that the node.js VM is capable of 1000 req/s. Seems like it's an nginx bottleneck because I can get 1000 req/s when going via nginx direct to any one of them.  If I know that each node app is capable of `1000 req/s`, why can't I achieve `4k req/s` with 4 `upstream` servers?

Any recommendations on good profiling software to use?

Answer (score 1):

The detail of the CPU and Memory utilisation on each node is needed to understand the bottleneck including the nginx proxy server.

Though, It is best practice to use the 'least_conn' parameter when you connect more than 2 upstream server in proxy. This will make sure the server load distribution is equal, prefer to the server with least load at that time.

You will get more info from 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

You may need to tune the Nginx as well. 
http://clouditops.blogspot.in/2016/11/improve-nginx-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't specified any attempts to diagnose or what kind of hardware you're developing on, you're not going to get very good answers.

I'd assume it's some kind of resource shortage due to your hardware. You're probably either maxing out your CPUs or saturating your network connection.

Each Node app gets its own thread, but if two of those threads are running on the same core then they could be impacting each others' performance. Even if each app is running on its own core, you could be saturating the bus.

If it's network saturation, that just means your apps are fighting for bandwidth and should be given better network isolation.

Finally, the computer running ApacheBench may be struggling to keep up.

In all cases, find yourself some hardware profilers and see what your hardware is doing because your servers are obviously a lot more powerful and are scaling just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Each node app is running on its own core, as each node app has it's own dedicated VM.  As you can see in my example, each node app has its own IP address.

Comment: As you can see in my example, each node app has its own IP address.  If it was network, I wouldn't expect to get 17k req/s with a different app (with a larger content length) running on the same servers...

Comment: You could have specified different IPs for each app inside a virtualized environment. You didn't make any of your details clear.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, each node app is running on a separate VM in digital ocean.  When using simple tools like `top`, I don't see any major bottlenecks.  Plus, I know when using a single upstream server that the node.js VM is capable of 1000 req/s.  Seems like it's an nginx bottleneck because I can get 1000 req/s when going via nginx direct to any one of them.  Any recommendations on good profiling software to use?

Comment: Please edit your original answer to provide these details.